# Deleting specific content of XML file

Tags: c++, xml, qt

In my xml file i have a node whose subchilder have 2 attributes, i have to delete 1 whole subchild while considering only 1 attribute. I have given an example below

XML file:

```js
<UMG>
  <ABC Name="ABC" Value="1"></ABC>
  <ABC Name="ABC1" Value="2"></ABC>
  <ABC Name="ABC2" Value="3"></ABC>
  <ABC Name="ABC3" Value="4"></ABC>
  <ABC Name="ABC4" Value="5"></ABC>
</UMG>
```

I have to delete the whole subchild with only "Name" attribute, because Value can be changed.

My code until now:

```
void::MainWindow::XML()
{
    QString path = ui->lineEdit_7->text();

    qDebug()<<path;
    if(!file.exists() )
        {
        qDebug() << "Check your file";
    }
    QDomDocument dom;
    dom.setContent(&file);
    QDomNodeList nodes = dom.elementsByTagName("ABC");

    QDomNodeList loc_childNodes = nodes.at(0).childNodes();

    for(int i=0; i<loc_childNodes.count(); i++)
    {
        QDomNode node = loc_childNodes.at(i);
        qDebug() << node.attributes().namedItem("Name").nodeValue(); // I get all Name attributes.
```

last qDebug gives me all "Name" attributes. I am stuck at deleting the subchild with using this information.

Edit:

```js
<NEW>
  <child>ABC<child>
  <child1>ABC1<child1>
  <Child3>ABC3<child3>
<NEW>
```

EDIT2:

```js
<MAIN>
  <SUB Name = "ABC" Value = "1"/>
  <SUB Name = "ABC1" Value = "0"/>
  <SUB Name = "ABC2" Value = "3"/>
  <Header Name = "Abc" value = "9"/>
  <SUB Name = "ABC7" Value = "3"/>
  <Header Name = "Abc5" value = "9"/>
  <SUB Name = "ABC3" Value = "3"/>
  <Header Name = "Abc0" value = "9"/>
</MAIN>
```

I want to delete only "SUB" attributes child. 
EXPECTED Result:

```js
<MAIN>
   <Header Name = "Abc" value = "9"/>
   <Header Name = "Abc5" value = "9"/>
   <Header Name = "Abc0" value = "9"/>
</MAIN>
```

EDit3:

```js
qDebug()<<manualoutput_scr;
    QString path = "File"
       QFile inFile(path );
           if( !inFile.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text ) )
           {
               qDebug( "Failed to open file for reading." );
           }

           QDomDocument dom;
           if( !dom.setContent( &inFile ) )
           {
               qDebug( "Failed to parse the file into a DOM tree." );
           }

           QDomElement docElem = dom.documentElement();
           QDomNodeList nodes = docElem.elementsByTagName("MAIN");
           QDomNodeList loc_childNodes = nodes.at(0).childNodes();
           for(int i=0; i<loc_childNodes.count(); i++)
              {
              QDomNode node = loc_childNodes.at(i);
              if( node.nodeName().compare("SUB") == 0  ) {
                  QDomNode parentNode = node.parentNode();
                  parentNode.removeChild(node);
              }
              }
           QFile outFile( path);
           if( !outFile.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text ) )
           {
               qDebug( "Failed to open file for writing." );
           }

           QTextStream stream( &outFile );
           stream << dom.toString();
           outFile.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QDomNode has method **removeChild** may be it help?

From doc

```
QDomNode QDomNode::removeChild(const QDomNode & oldChild)
```

> Removes oldChild from the list of children. oldChild must be a direct
>   child of this node. Returns a new reference to oldChild on success or
>   a null node on failure.

**Addition** Your code may looks something like follow

```
if( node.attributes().namedItem("Name").nodeValue().compare("ABC3") == 0  ) {
    QDomNode parentNode = node.parentNode();
    parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
```

**Addition** to Edit 2

```
if( node.nodeName().compare("SUB") == 0  ) {
    QDomNode parentNode = node.parentNode();
    parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
```

Update To Edit 3. Replace the lines

```
QDomElement docElem = dom.documentElement();
QDomNodeList nodes = docElem.elementsByTagName("MAIN");
```

with

```
QDomNodeList nodes = dom.elementsByTagName("MAIN");
```

and after parent.removeChild(node) add i-=1, because a count of elements is decreased.
And don't forget to close the file ("File") inFile.close() before to call outFile.open()

Comment: How do i define a child, i did try with " QDomElement cild = node.attributes().namedItem("Name").nodeValue() == "ABC3"

Comment: if it works, why not? Then call method parentNode and remove the childNode.
Something like this
parent = childNode.parentNode(); parent.removeChild(childNode);

Comment: I cannot declare the child " QDomElement cild = node.attributes().namedItem("Name").nodeValue() == "ABC3", I keep getting ": error: C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'bool' to 'QDomElement'
No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous"

Comment: if( node.attributes().namedItem("Name").nodeValue().compare("ABC3") == 0  ) {
    QDomNode parentNode = node.parentNode();
    parentNode.removeChild(node);
}

and don't forget rtfm :)

Comment: Thanks! Work! Can you tell me how do i delete a node without any attribute, i have mentioned a examaple in my main post

Comment: Same way. That is
if( node.attributes().isEmpty() ) {
   // get the parent and remove the child
}

Comment: @Alexander_Chernin Can you please look at EDIT2 in the main post.

Comment: @user5820174 completed

Comment: @Alexander_Chernin, What exactly is nodeName(), doesn't seem it work

Comment: I have added my full code to my main post. see EDIT3 please

Comment: nodeName at this context is a tag name, and I think found a mistake look at the update above